# Debugging JavaScript with Eclipse 

Tags: jquery, eclipse, firebug, firephp

What is the best way to debug javascript from the eclipse IDE. I used "logging to console" features of firebug with firephp installed on top of it for debugging a kohana php project along with eclipse  but they make the browser unstable when I make extensive use of jQuery. For example, "Permission denied to...a non-chrome context..." is one such error that is frequent in firebug.

Comment: If you're using Firebug why do you want to debug within Eclipse?  Firebug has a wonderful JS debugger built-in.

Comment: I guess you meant "Permission denied to...a non-chrome context..." is one such error that is frequently *reported by* firebug.   This is not an error caused by Firebug. Firebug + FirePHP do not make the browser 'unstable'; you have some other problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [**ATF** (Ajax Tools Framework)](http://www.eclipse.org/atf/)

> ATF provides tooling that allows a user to edit, debug, and monitor CSS, HTML, and JavaScript applications and a framework on which adopters can build advanced and technology specific tools.
>   The functionality in ATF breaks down into three main areas:
>
> - Browser Tooling, [image: JsConsole]
> - JavaScript Debugger [image: DebuggerBreakpoints]
> - extensions for adopters

See [this demo](http://www.eclipse.org/atf/flash/index4.php), the [ATF Help page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/ATF/Help), and [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/atf-dev/msg00627.html).

[image: Collage]

Answer (score 0):

For Node.js there is [Nodeclipse 0.2](http://github.com/nodeclipse/) with some bug fixes for [chromedevtools](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/)